# Simple SQL UNION ALL very slow

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The sql statement is a simple union all between two queries. Each one on its own is instantaneous. Union all them however and it becomes 20x slower. Any help is appreciated.

```
SELECT 
     1
FROM 
     [fnGetEmployeeProfileDoctorsMultiplePeriods](
          @FromPeriodId, 
          @ToPeriodId, 
          @ProfileId, 
          @EmployeeId, 
          @GeographicalAreaId, 
          @DoctorId, 
          @TeamId
     )
UNION ALL   
SELECT 
     1
FROM 
     [fnGetEmployeeProfileOrganizationsMultiplePeriods](
          @FromPeriodId, 
          @ToPeriodId, 
          @ProfileId, 
          @EmployeeId, 
          @GeographicalAreaId, 
          @DoctorId, 
          @TeamId
      )
```

**Update**:

It seems that adding the union operator causes the execution plan for the two sub-queries to change; the query engine does not simply concatenate the two original plans. Using the option recompile flag fixes this (or rather, creates a much faster plan), so how can one force it to use the recompiled plan instead?

Plan links:

Slow version

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyZq2Ybbb

Quick version with option(recompile) set

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJ5bpYbZZ

**Update 2:**

After much optimization in the two subqueries, the symptoms remain, but the execution plans now don't change on adding the union operator. Also, if you use a top operator in a way that obtains the results from only the first subquery (or, surprise, only the second one), the results come back immediately. 'Cross the border' and request results from both however, and a 5 second penalty is added.

Comment: One suspects it is the UDF and not the `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Why would the UDF matter? Each of these calls takes 1 sec, so why would a union all take 15? It should be a simple concatenation, nothing more

Comment: Check out your execution plan, but I might suspect parameter sniffing.

Comment: @mido Maybe check your table indexes too. They can be in most cases the slowness source in a db.

Comment: @mido do an `EXPLAIN` for selecting on each table. Maybe you see something suspect. And then on the union too.

Comment: Share your execution plans using [Paste The Plan @ brentozar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) here are the instructions: [How to Use Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/).

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried inserting each function into a temp table and then querying the temp table instead? For instance, you would create the temp table and then have separate insert statements for each function.

```
CREATE TABLE #Employee
(
Record INT 
) 


INSERT INTO #Employee
    ( Record )

SELECT 1
FROM [fnGetEmployeeProfileDoctorsMultiplePeriods](@FromPeriodId, @ToPeriodId, @ProfileId, @EmployeeId, @GeographicalAreaId, @DoctorId, @TeamId)


INSERT INTO #Employee
    ( Record )

SELECT 1
FROM [fnGetEmployeeProfileOrganizationsMultiplePeriods](@FromPeriodId, @ToPeriodId, @ProfileId, @EmployeeId, @GeographicalAreaId, @DoctorId, @TeamId)


SELECT * 
FROM #Employee
```

Answer (score 1):

I am betting that your table valued functions are multi statement table valued functions. If possible, rewrite them as inline table valued functions.

Inline table-valued functions vs scalar and multi-statement table-valued functions

> "If it’s not inline, it’s rubbish." - Rob Farley

Reference:

- [When is a SQL function not a function? "If it’s not inline, it’s rubbish." - Rob Farley](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2011/11/08/when-is-a-sql-function-not-a-function/)
- [Inline Scalar Functions - Itzik Ben-Gan](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/inline-scalar-functions)
- [Scalar functions, inlining, and performance: An entertaining title for a boring post - Adam Machanic](http://dataeducation.com/scalar-functions-inlining-and-performance-an-entertaining-title-for-a-boring-post/)
- [TSQL User-Defined Functions: Ten Questions You Were Too Shy To Ask - Robert Sheldon](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/tsql-user-defined-functions-ten-questions-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/)

Comment: They're inline I'm afraid, but you're correct; multi statement functions should be avoided

Comment: @mido post the creation scripts for them.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.

```
--Requete 67. Performance cost 6%
SELECT * 
INTO #temp_arbo_of_6 
FROM (
SELECT * FROM #temp_arbo_of_4
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM #temp_arbo_of_5
) AS tmp;
```

each table has 60 columns. Takes up 6% of the global timing of an analytic stored procedure. It shouldn't.

Solved it this way:

```
--Requete 67. Performance cost 0%
INSERT INTO #temp_arbo_of_4
SELECT * FROM #temp_arbo_of_5;
```

and then using #temp_arbo_of_4 instead of #temp_arbo_of_6. I didn't need both.